# Is Facebook blocking my script via some kind of "defense mechanism" (maybe React based)?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I tried to run the following script with Tampermonkey to hide all images in [Facebook](http://facebook.com) for a more minimal usage experience, yet no image is hidden in any webpage there.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(el) {
el.style.display = "none";
});
```

1. There are no errors in Tampermonkey.
2. The script is on at each relevant webpage under facebook.com.

Maybe Facebook's React has a way of filtering such a script? If so, I ask what can be done from my end, if at all.

Update:

Sadly all 3 answers didn't work. Try them (originals) in a script targeting all Facebook webpages if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var n = images.length; n--> 0;) {
  var img = images[n];
  img.setAttribute("src", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please explain why this works and the previous code piece didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but the problem is that the images are constantly being generated so you need to continually set the display.

```
setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(el => { 
         el.style.display = "none"
    }
}), 30);
```

A better way would probably be to inject a global style [1](https://somethingididnotknow.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/change-page-styles-with-greasemonkeytampermonkey/).

```
function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Comment: I am new and have never seen such codes (that seem very interesting). I would thumb up if I could but I lack 2 more points to do so. Can you please elaborate on what is actually being done in these 2 codes? Thanks.

Comment: Sadly it seems both solutions doesn't vanish images on Facebook.